# How would one use a custom domain name with abp framework

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I'm sure this is nothing new, but perhaps I do not know the right thing to type into google... essentially my goal is to create a multi tenant application using abp.io with the following requirement.

1. A new user registers as a tenant.
2. The user then points their domains dns records to my application.
3. The user inputs the custom domain to use for their tenant.
4. The users login and pages will resolve on their selected domain.

For example, my applications name is hosted on winemaker.com. Someone who makes wine wants to use my application and signs up with the tenant name of JoesFootWine (winemaker.com/JoesFootWine)... But Joe already owns the domain JoesFootWine.com and would like to use that for this application. I need to set up a way for Joe to easily set up their tenant such that winemaker.com/JoesFootWine is resolved on  JoesFootWine.com.

It would be an added bonus but not a hard requirement that a login page would be set up on JoesFootWine.com/{login-route} and the tenant is already set and not changeable.

Answer (score 3):

The trickiest thing to do here will be resolving the tenant based on the domain. I've done this before with ABP but cannot remember all of the details but you can create your own custom Tenant resolver using the ITenantResolveContributor interface. Then your resolver can be used instead of the default one.

Docs for that are here https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy

In your custom tenant resolver you need to get the domain currently being used and then use that domain to look up the tenant in the database. You might store those in a seperate table in-case you want to allow the tenant to have multiple domain names etc or it could just be a column in the Tenant table. From memory it's a bit tricky to get the domain from an api call in Aspnet core compared to MVC forms or something.

If it's an api call you need to resolve the tenant for then I think you should be able to get the domain from the referrer

Actually I just dug up this. I think there is most likely a better way to do this but hope it might help get you started.

```
        //first try the referrer to see if we can resolve the tenant
        //this will be the referrer from the client calling the api
        var referer = httpContext.Request.Headers.Any(x => x.Key.Equals("referer", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) ? httpContext.Request.Headers["Referer"].ToString() : "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
        {
            Uri myUri = new Uri(referer);
            referer = myUri.Host;
        }

        //if no referrer then resort to the host
        //currently this will not change based on tenant
        //but could be an option with some more customization instead 
        //of relying on referrer. 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(referer))
            referer = httpContext.Request.Host.Host;
```

I also recall that there isn't something extra I needed to do on the UI side of things in Angular routing or something. Can't really remember now as was more than a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved to some extend as your business model seems heavily dependant on SignInManager modification and url re-writes.

> A new user registers as a tenant.

To achieve this, you need to create a tenant when registering a new user on your `CustomSignInManager`. You can see [this article](https://community.abp.io/articles/how-to-customize-the-signin-manager-3e858753) about how customize it. Key point is tenant names **must be unique**. So if there are two *JoesFootWine*s around, you need to handle that business case.

> The user then points their domains dns records to my application

Seems the last step but Ok.

> The user inputs the custom domain to use for their tenant.

You can keep this data in a different entity or extend TenantEntity.

> The users login and pages will resolve on their selected domain.

I am not sure how or if you can resolve login or any other page can be resolved in tenant's domain.

> It would be an added bonus but not a hard requirement that a login
> page would be set up on JoesFootWine.com/{login-route} and the tenant
> is already set and not changeable

I can't think of an easy way to achieve this. You want to de-centeralize the login page for each tenant on your 4th step if i understand correctly. This means, you need to check which domain they're visiting from and have a specific login page for that tenant with hidden tenant name already entered to `Select Tenant` inputbox. Or a switch case inputboxes on the same login page. I am not sure if this can be achieved.