# Using subdomain is not resolving to a tenant

Tags: abp

So I'm attempting to use subdomains using the tenant's name to resolve such.  In my case, working in local host, I edited my host file to point to a new tenant named subdomains to the localhost application.

I'm able to go-to the page and it loads properly using test.mydomain.com:[port] but it does not seem to honour the domaintenantresolver I set up in ConfigureServices.  Is this a completely wrong approach to test subdomain multitenancy?

The code below is the function I added in which I call in ConfigureServices.  I also added the following lines to my host file:
127.0.0.1       [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
127.0.0.1       [www.meme.mydomain.com](http://www.meme.mydomain.com)

```
private void ConfigureTenantResolver(ServiceConfigurationContext context, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      
        Configure<AbpTenantResolveOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.TenantResolvers.Insert(1, new DomainTenantResolveContributor($"{0}.mydomain.com:44327"));
            // OR
            // options.AddDomainTenantResolver($"{0}.mydomain.com:44327");
    
          
            options.TenantResolvers.Add(new QueryStringTenantResolveContributor());
            options.TenantResolvers.Add(new RouteTenantResolveContributor());
            options.TenantResolvers.Add(new HeaderTenantResolveContributor());
            options.TenantResolvers.Add(new CookieTenantResolveContributor());
        });
    }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I sent this sprawled out on the floor from my phone after some hours of frustration, let me edit my post now with some examples from my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would one use a custom domain name with abp framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63946118/how-would-one-use-a-custom-domain-name-with-abp-framework)

Comment: Not entirely, but it may be the direction I have to try if the default AddDomainTenantResolver will not work which is what I grabbed from their documentation

Comment: Try without port when passing to `DomainTenantResolveContributor`?

Comment: @Cowmoogun, I am not sure if you meant to use string interpolation here - `$"{0}.mydomain.com:44327"`. Maybe try changing it to `"{0}.mydomain.com:44327"`

Comment: @NikhilPatil, it looks like that is a part of the syntax used for that method call.  https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Multi-Tenancy